# Windows Application for broadcasting the screen through the local network

Tags: windows, video

I am going to teach a group of 5 people. I want to broadcast my screen to other users(students). What software you can suggest for this purpose?

- Paid/Free: it does not matter
- Requirement: it should work on local network
- Direction: one direction(teacher to student) is more than enough
- OS: Windows 8.1 (RAM: 4Gb HDD: 500Gb)

Comment: What about using projector? I TA programming course and using projector is more comfortable, because students can follow, and copy from board; rather than constantly switch windows.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Problem is here, because of projector absence. That's why I need this app!)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/index.aspx).TeamViewer is offered free of charge to everybody for personal, non-commercial use

**Examples for non-commercial use:**
- Helping or supporting friends and relatives
- Connecting to your private home pc from school, university or vacation

**Examples for commercial use:**
- Helping or supporting customers or colleagues at work
- Connecting to your company pc or server from your home office

**Note:To use LAN mode in Team-viewer You and the remote machines must connected to team-viewer's keep alive server which means that it requires internet**

### Instruction to [configure](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx) Team-viewer LAN mode

You can establish Remote control sessions on your local network directly by using IP addresses or computer names. By default this feature is deactivated because software firewalls may open an acceptance dialog when configured this way.

To activate the LAN mode in TeamViewer full version and Host module:

- In the menu click on Extras and then on Options
- On the General tab activate Accept incoming LAN connections

**When selecting accept exclusively it will display the IP-address of the computer in the ID-field Then a connection can now be established using the IP-address or alternatively using the host name.**

[image]